# Organizing Images in Eclipse IDE for Java

Tags: java, eclipse, image, directory

I am making a simple game and I am using a lot of images.

However, I don't know how to put them to folders and still be able to load them in the project.

For now I just put them in the root of the project and load them as

```
new ImageIcon("test.png")
```

Is there a way to put them in a folder and still be easily accessible ?

Comment: add the respective directory/folder in the build path and use it with folder/test.png in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Structure

```
--Root
    |
    --folder
         |
         -- test.png
```

### Code

```
new ImageIcon("folder/test.png");
```